# How do I give separate menus to my two user types in python using sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

My program requires a student type user and a teacher type user. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to show different menus based on what their user type is. The program would have different menus for each based on whether they are a student or a teacher, each with their own functions and uses.

```
def studmain():
    screen3 = Tk()
    screen3.geometry("500x500")
    screen3.title("Student Menu")
    screen3.mainloop

def teachmain():
    screen4 = Tk()
    screen4.geometry("500x500")
    screen4.title("Teacher Menu")
    screen4.mainloop

def loginfunc():
    while True:
        with sqlite3.connect('MyComputerScience.db') as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
        find_user = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?")
        cursor.execute(find_user, (username.get(), password.get()))
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        if results:
            for i in results:
                Label(screen1, text = "Log-in successful!", fg = "GREEN", font = "Calibri").pack()
                find_type = ("Select * FROM users WHERE usertype = Teacher")
                results = cursor.fetchall()
                if results:
                    for i in results:
                        teachmain()
                else:
                    studmain()


        else:
            Label(screen1, text = "Log-in unsuccessful!", fg = "RED", font = "Calibri").pack()
            login()
        break
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show where you want this menu or anything like that. Also, why the `while True` when you always `break` at the end?

Comment: The menu would be after the program identifies the users, and there's a lot of breaks because I just forgot to remove them

Comment: What I meant with my first sentence: please show at least how you would put a single menu. We don't do mind-reading here.

Comment: I've added what I tried to do, however both ways it only shows the student menu, even when I log in as someone I registered as a teacher

Comment: First, I will guess that the username is a unique (primary) key.  If that is not the case then I would review the table design.  If it is a primary key, then you should get precisely one or zero records back.  Why use a for loop?  That would be very awkward (besides being insecure) if the results actually contained multiple records and it logged in multiple users repeatedly.  I suppose a for loop works for just one record also, but it looks awkward.  Also, the `usertype` field is already retrieved in the first query (i.e. from `SELECT *`) so there is no need for the second query.

Comment: Okay, so the code is deceiving since it contains unused code.  It is *not* executing the second query.  The code is actually calling `fetchall()` on the same cursor that was executing previously, but since it already retrieved the data then it is probably returning 0 new records.  Thus, the subsequent `if` statement is probably always false so that the student menu will always be displayed.

Comment: Moral of the story:  Trace through the code manually, inspecting each line to ensure that it makes sense logically.  Actively step through the running code (i.e. live debug) and inspect values of variables, then when something doesn't seem correct, trace backward, asking yourself why and where the values comes from, etc.  Look for unused code and/or pay attention to compiler warnings, etc.  (Of course I doubt that python actually flags that sort of thing.)